# FireFox Profile Error

Tags: firefox

I am getting this https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0.1/firstrun/learnmore/ while running my script in Firefox. This was running just fine until last week but it has stopped working now. I renamed and deleted the Firefox profile but that didn't help. Here are the error I am receiving in Eclipse. Any help will be appreciated.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ddons.xpi   DEBUG   checkForChanges
1450818781417   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\sluite\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous4238069008057039774webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1450818779415,"mt":1450818779275}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"43.0.1","st":1450741870041,"mt":1450322003000}}}
1450818781418   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1450818781418   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1450818781419   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1450818781419   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\sluite\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous4238069008057039774webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1450818779415,"mt":1450818779275}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"43.0.1","st":1450741870041,"mt":1450322003000}}}
1450818781420   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1450818781426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1450818781426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1450818781426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1450818781426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1450818781427   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1450818781427   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1450818781431   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1450818781431   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1450818781431   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1450818781431   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1450818781432   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1450818781432   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1450818781497   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\sluite\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4238069008057039774webdriver-profile\extensions.json
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1450818781568   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1450818781568   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1450818781568   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1450818781653   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1450818781653   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1450818781653   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1450818781711   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1450818781711   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1450818781712   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1450818825183   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1450818825183   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1450818825184   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1450818825184   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1450818825184   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1450818825184   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1450818825185   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1450818825186   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1450818825187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1450818825189   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1450818825191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at WindowsHandle.HandleACLPopUP.baseURL(HandleACLPopUP.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: What is your script you run? On what page do you run the script? What does the link https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0.1/firstrun/learnmore/ have to do with your script?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems fixed in recent versions of FirefoxDriver. If you are not using latest version of FirefoxDriver, please upgrade it to 2.49.1 (latest version)